# Footer sort elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to put my 3 footer elements in one single row.

The first element should take 50% of the space and the rest of the 2 element should take 25% each.

I have tried my best to sort those 3 elements in the right order. 
But I do not have any idea why my 3 elements are not in a single row and where the width of those 3 elements will be (50%, 25%, 25%)

I have created a  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uzzimu/r7n6x6d3/1/) 
here, where you can see the 3 elements are not sorted in a correct way.

Can anyone have an idea how to fix this issue !!!

CODE---

```
  <footer class="mdl-mega-footer" style="background: #ffffff">
    <div class="mdl-mega-footer--middle-section">
      <div class="mdl-grid">
        <div class="mdl-mega-footer--drop-down-section">
          <img src="public/images/office.jpg" alt="office" height="42" width="82">
          <input class="mdl-mega-footer--heading-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked>
          <ul class="mdl-mega-footer--link-list">
            <p> This is just some test datas. This is just some test datas. This is just some test datas. This is just some test datas. This is just some test datas. This is just some test datas. This is just some test datas. This is just some test datas. This is just some test datas. This is just some test datas. This is just some test datas. This is just some test datas. This is just some test datas. </p>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="mdl-mega-footer--drop-down-section">
        <input class="mdl-mega-footer--heading-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked>
        <h1 class="mdl-mega-footer--heading">Bestsellers</h1>
        <ul class="mdl-mega-footer--link-list">
          <li><a href="#">• A4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">• A5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">• Pens</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">• Staplers</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-mega-footer--drop-down-section">
        <input class="mdl-mega-footer--heading-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked>
        <h1 class="mdl-mega-footer--heading">We're social! </h1>
        <ul class="mdl-mega-footer--link-list">
          <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">LinkedIn</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've correctly started the mdl-grid div, but you need to put each item you want on the row in an mdl-cell div. Specifically, since you want 50%, 25% and 25% and the number of columns available is 12, your divs should be 6 columns, 3 columns and 3 columns.

```
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">Big Column</div>
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col">Middle Column</div>
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col">Right Column</div>
```

Here's a fork of your [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8sh3dgqk/)

EDIT: It looks like some of your mega footer class names should have double underscores instead of double dashes.

```
mdl-mega-footer__middle-section
```

And it also appears the example mega-footer listed [here](https://getmdl.io/components/#layout-section/footer)  has the same mistake so I can see why you were confused! It always sucks when the teaching material is incorrect!